# Halachic consequences of raping one's wife

Tags: halacha, marriage, sexuality

The Gemorah in [Nedorim 20b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.20b?lang=en) brings a list of 9/10 "warnings"/"prohibitions" on sexual relationships with one's wife, with rape being the first. However, the Gemmorah does not mention any punishment, besides the"Heavenly" punishment of having troublesome children from such relations.

Ra"n adds in place that such relations are a sort of transgression, but not a clear one. And I didn't see interpreters developing that idea.

Does a woman have any case in complaining before a Beis Din about being raped by her husband, and how can the Bais Din punish or take measures against the husband?

Comment: "Ra"n adds in place [sic] that such relations are a sort of transgression, but not a clear one" I am not seeing that in the Ran. Consider adding a link.

Comment: Rape violates just about every interpersonal mitsvah, treating others as one would want to be treated, etc. It seems unlikely that raping would be more lenient than hurting someone verbally, which is itself biblically forbidden.

Comment: @Mevakesh: 1. https://www.sefaria.org/Ran_on_Nedarim.20b.8?lang=he

Comment: @Mevakesh Of course it transgresses "all other commandments", but specifically I could not find one. The consent of the wife seems to be a "nice to have" but not necessary. I saw someone mentions, that if she was hurt in the process, the husband pays the damages just like any physical damage and is "anyway" obligated to heal her, but nothing special beyond. And, of course, as it's all Mamonos, nothing criminal.

Comment: The Ran isnt saying that none of them are actual sins. He is saying that the common denoominator is that they have צד עבירה. This of course is Biblically forbidden due to ואהבת לרעך כמוך. || BTW my name is meva**q**esh.

Comment: Robbery and assault are also "Mamonos". I believe they also qualify as "criminal".

Comment: @Loewian hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1096&pgnum=241 last paragraph on the right, it is not robbery or assault.  but if it was assault he needs to pay see https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.83.2 and https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.83.1 end

Comment: @mevaqesh Better later... I rewrote the title - is it good now?

Comment: @AlBerko אין בכוונתי להאריך בזה באנגלית, אבל עי' ברמב"ם (הל' איסו"ב, פכ"א, הל"י/ט) בועל בכל עת שירצה", וכן נפסק בטור (אבהע"ז, סי' כה), וברמ"א שם (סעי' ב). לפי זה נראה פשוט, שאין בית דין נזקקים לטענתה, וכן אין מענישים אותו, כיון שמתוקף נישואיה היא משועבדת לו בכל עת שירצה. ואין הכי נמי שנהג עמה בצורה לא הוגנת, כיון שלמעשה בעל צריך להתחשב עם אשתו בענינים הללו, אבל מכל מקום, סוף סוף הרי משועבדת היא לו. ואם כנים הדברים, נראה לענ"ד שיש מקום לומר, שבכה"ג גם אינו עובר על "ואהבת לרעך כמוך", כיון שגם היא במקומו, כם כן היתה תובעת שיעבודה, בדיוק כמו שהוא תבע ממנה לקיים מה שהיא משועבדת לו.

Comment: @IsraelReader Who wrote this? And what about monetary claims - צער, נזק

Comment: @AlBerko כן נראה לענ"ד, וקבל את האמת ממי שאמרו. - לא הוזכר בגמרא נדרים שהיה צער או נזק, אלא שסתם אנס אותה. - במקרה שהיה נזק, היא סוגיא ערוכה (ב"ק לב א) המזיק את אשתו בתשמיש המטה מהו וכו', ויש בזה מחלוקת אמוראים, לפי רב הונא, פטור, ולפי רבא, חייב. ההלכה נפסקה כרבא (רמב"ם חובל ד יז; טוש"ע חו"מ תכא יב, ואהע"ז סוף סי' פג). - ולענין צער, נחלקו ראשונים, יש סוברים שהוא חייב בד' דברים, ויש סוברים שאינו חייב אלא על הנזק. - ועי' במאירי שם, שמדובר בהיזק שהיה יכול להישמר ממנו, וע"ש בגמרא "איבעי ליה לעיוני", וכן ע"ש בר"ח, וברא"ש (פ"ד, אות י). ויש לדון בכה"ג שהצער והנזק בא רק מחמת שהתנגדה להיות עמו.

Comment: @Israel  בועל בכל עת שירצה לאפוקי נידה שעדיין אסור לבעול בגנות ופרדסים אפילו אם יתעב לכך, וכן כשאשתו לא מרשה, ואם תסרב בקביעות ומפסיד עונתה הוי מורדת וגוערים מכתובתה אבל  לא מרשים לבעל לבעול בחוזק ח"ו. ומי יאמר לך שאילו היא היתה במקומו לא היתה חס על רצון אישה כדרך נשים רחמניות? רעיך, לא צריך. בני אברהם אבינו. ומי שאוכף שעבודו יותר מאורח כל ארעא נכנס לחשש מקח טעות

Comment: @DoubleAA I never condoned such activity. In fact I wrote, critically, that שנהג עמה בצורה לא הוגנת, כיון שלמעשה בעל צריך להתחשב עם אשתו בענינים הללו. That being said, the fact is that we don’t find halachic sanctions against him for acting so. - The exceptions of Nidda (punishable by כרת) and gardens and orchards (corporal punishment: Rambam, Issurei Biah 21:14; Shulchan Aruch, EH 25:4) are clearly sourced. - A source for כשאשתו לא מרשה, is the Gemara in Nedarim 20b cited in the OP, which doesn’t explicitly prohibit it, but also doesn’t provide for any halachic sanctions against him.

Comment: @Israel ממתי צריכים מקור למכת מרדות באיסור בין אדם לחברו שלא בממון המוחש ע"י החכמים כלאו מפורש? גנות ופרדסים ניחא, אבל מה עם הבועל לאור הנר, והבועל בשעת וסתה, והבועל בשני רעבון וכדו'. וכל עניין מכת מרדות היא לפי צורך השעה ועיני הדיונים. ואיזהו חכם הרואה את הנולד שלא התקיף יד ב"ד בין אדם לאשתו ומקום השאיר להם להתגרד בו ולעסוק בענייני צניעות בצניעות כדבעי שאפילו לחוקי חושן משפט יש גבול.

Comment: @DoubleAA (continued) See also Pesachim 49b מה ארי דורס ואוכל ואין לו בושת פנים אף עם הארץ מכה ובועל ואין לו בושת פנים, and Tosfos (ad loc. s.v. Mah) עם הארץ אינו ממתין עד שתתפייס, that this type of conduct is described as typical as that of an Am Haaretz, but still, no Beis Din involvement.
Also see Eiruvin (100b) ואמר רמי בר חמא אמר רב אסי, אסור לאדם שיכוף אשתו לדבר מצוה וכו'. וא"ר יהושע בן לוי, כל הכופה אשתו לדבר מצוה, הווין לו בנים שאינן מהוגנין. Again, prohibited, but no punishment by Beis Din.

Comment: @DoubleAA If in response to the OP, you posit that Beis Din will sanction him, then you need to provide a source for this. I showed several sources that decried the form of activity, yet make no mention of BD sanctions. The silence of Chazal is deafening!

Comment: @Israel deafening? I can barely hear it. (As in, I don't find your argument from silence compelling, though obviously that's an opinion.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I answered the OP's question. If you were a dayan in BD, and a woman came and presented such a complaint, what would YOU rule, and what would be the halachic basis for such a ruling?

Comment: @Israel I'd tell them to seek counseling. Dayanim nowadays don't enforce most things. (If it was particularly obscene I might threaten him with Nidui.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE**: the virtually same answer was posted for a more general question "[What damages does a hurting husband pay to his wife](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104260/18474)?"*

---

**Rambam** [Hilchos Chovel U'Mazik 4:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_One_Who_Injures_a_Person_or_Property.4.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וְהַמַּזִּיק אִשְׁתּוֹ בְּתַשְׁמִישׁ הַמִּטָּה חַיָּב בִּנְזָקֶיהָ:
>
> When a person injures his wife through marital relations, he is liable for the damages.

This isn't necessarily referring to rape. However the **Rambam** writes in the previous halacha
[Hilchos Chovel U'Mazik 4:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_One_Who_Injures_a_Person_or_Property.4.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) :

> בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים שֶׁחָבְלוּ בָּהּ אֲחֵרִים. **אֲבָל הַבַּעַל שֶׁחָבַל בְּאִשְׁתּוֹ חַיָּב לְשַׁלֵּם לָהּ מִיָּד כָּל הַנֵּזֶק וְכָל הַבּשֶׁת וְהַצַּעַר וְהַכּל שֶׁלָּהּ** וְאֵין לַבַּעַל בָּהֶן פֵּרוֹת. וְאִם רָצְתָה לִתֵּן הַדָּמִים לְאַחֵר נוֹתֶנֶת. וְכָזֶה הוֹרוּ הַגְּאוֹנִים. וְהַבַּעַל מְרַפֵּא אוֹתָהּ כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁמְּרַפֵּא כָּל חָלְיָהּ:
>
> When does the above apply? When others injured her. **When, however, a husband injures his wife, he is required to pay her the entire assessment for the damages, the embarrassment and the pain. This money is hers entirely.** The husband has no rights to the profits. If she desires to give the money to another person, she may. This is the ruling rendered by the geonim. The husband must pay for her medical expenses, as he pays for all her other medical expenses.

Neither of these halachot from Hilchos Chovel U'Mazik explicitly address the punishment if a husband rapes his wife, but from here we can see that the husband is punished regardless.

Both of these halachos are codified by the **Shulchan Aruch**, [Even Haezer 83:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.83.1-2?lang=bi)

Comment: Great, you mean it is not called a RAPE anywhere, because it's his wife. It's plain damages.